# How to automate clicking in a 3rd-party Java applet?

Tags: c#, java, user-interface, automation, watin

Okay, here's my problem: I'm using WatiN to navigate a website, but then a java applet pops up in a separate window. Ideally, I'd like to automate that window (list box selections, key presses and the like) with something like the equivalent of NUnitForms or something... can someone give me a suggestion on how to do it? Note that I don't have the applet's source code, it's 3rd-party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/robot-class-java-awt/

Here is a tutorial on using the Robot class

Comment: This is nice, but I need something to the tune of being able to pick items from list programmatically, stuff like that.

Comment: This is just a dead link without any relevant info.

Comment: Updated link that was no longer